# More elegant way of displaying distributions and activations in TensorBoard

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorboard, tf.keras

Keras's Tensorboard callback has a `write_images` and a `histogram_freq` argument that allows the weights and activations to be saved to Tensorboard to visualize during training.

The issue is, this saves the information for every layer and makes Tensorboard very messy, especially if I have logged other images to Tensorboard. This can be seen in the images below:

[image]
[image]

A lot of this logged information is redundant. Is there any way to make the weight distribution and activation visualizations more organized? Is there any way to only visualize certain layers?

Comment: Could you please provide some source code?